# What is the "generic solution" of the heat equation $U_t=k^2 U_{xx}$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, heat-equation

Aside from solutions that one obtains depending on initial and or boundary conditions (using fundamental solution or eigenfunctions depending on domain)  is there a "generic solution" of the heat equation?

For example for the wave equation $U_{tt} =c^2 U_{xx}$  we have  $U=f(x-ct)+g(x+ct)$ for any smooth functions $f,g$.

Are there papers discussing the solution of $U_t+a^2U_{tt}=c^2 U_{xx}$ as $a \to 0$ ?

Comment: The one-dimensional wave equation is very special because it factors as $(\partial_t - c \partial_x)(\partial_t + c \partial_x) U = 0$; a factorization of this kind isn't available for the wave equation in any higher dimension, or for the heat equation in any dimension.

Comment: The heat equation doesn't really have characteristics in the same way that the wave equation does.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan What will we see if we solve $U_t+a^2U_{tt}=k^2 U_{xx}$ as $a \to 0$? Any recommended papers?

Comment: Isn't separation of variables the standard way to solve? Or Fourier transform.